# Pinterest endpoint to get pins data

Tags: pinterest-api

I am going through docs for Pinterest v5 api and I am not able to find endpoint that would allow me to fetch any pin data, something similar to this one:http://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/pins/info/?pin_ids=521150988102375972,10133167885969245 . I found it in this thread. What weird thing is that I didn't find that endpoint to be documented in v3 docs.

Their `https://api.pinterest.com/v5/pins/{pin_id}` fetches only pins that belong to the account that token was generated for.

Does anyone know of an endpoint that would allow to fetch pin data using pintrest v5 API?

Went trhough the docs and was not able to find an endpoint that could be suitable for my use case.